# Scraping multiple web pages with BeautifulSoup when the first page link is different from others

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I'm trying to scrape this [page](https://www.olx.com.ng/vehicles/cars/toyota/?search%5Bfilter_enum_model%5D%5B0%5D=toyota%2Fcamry)! for a project i'm working on. I want to get the details (Price, Mileage, Transmission, and Age) of each car for all the pages. The issues I'm having with my code below are:

1. The first page link is different from others (No page number 1 <&page=1>)
2. The price of the car is not inside the table after clicking on each ad to get the details.

I'm wondering if anyone would be kind enough to help me look into this and advise. Thanks

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import urllib.parse
    import csv

    # the Toyota Camry model page is used
    url = "https://www.olx.com.ng/vehicles/cars/toyota/?search%5Bfilter_enum_model%5D%5B0%5D=toyota%2Fcamry"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    carLinks = set()
    pageLinks = set()
    data_set = []

    parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(soup.select('a')[0].get('href'))
    nbPage = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['page'][1]
    print("There are " + str(nbPage) + " web pages to process")

    # for each web page that contains a grid of car offers
    for i in range(1, int(nbPage), 1):

    print("Processing web page: " + str(i))

    # each car offer link is saved into the carLinks
    for link in soup.select('#listContainer > div > section > div > tr > a'):
    carLinks.add(link.get('href').replace("//", "http://"))

    # the next url page is set
    url = "https://www.olx.com.ng/vehicles/cars/toyota/?
    search%5Bfilter_enum_model%5D%5B0%5D=toyota%2Fcamry&page= + str(i) + "
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

    #for each car link
    for carLink in carLinks:

    print("Processing car page: " + carLink)

    # we load the car page
    r = requests.get(carLink)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    km = 0
    transmission = ""
    age = 0
    price = 0

    # for each attribute of the car
    for info in soup.select("table.item tr div.pricelabel"):

    # we keep the ones that we need
    if info.select('.item')[0].text == u'Mileage':
        km = int(info.select('.value')[0].text.replace(" ", "").replace("KM", ""))
    if info.select('.item')[0].text == u'Transmission':
        transmission = info.select('.value')[0].text
    if info.select('.item')[0].text == u'Year':
        age = 2017 - int(info.select('.value')[0].text)
    if info.select('.pricelabel')[0].text == u'Price':
        price = int(info.select('.pricelabel')[0].text.replace(" ", "").replace(u"₦", ""))

    # each car is an array of four features added to the data_set
    data_set.append([km, transmission, age, price])

    # the data_set is save into the CSV file
    fl = open('car_features.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(fl)
    writer.writerow(['km', 'transmission', 'age', 'price'])
    for values in data_set:
    writer.writerow(values)

    fl.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *site is badly broken*, if you keep going to a next page, you eventually hit  a loading loop on the browser, for me page 501 returned to 500 if i pasted it directly, if I used the next from 500 where I can see 501, I get a loading loop that never ends, we use a redirect back to the previous to terminate our loop.

I have also used [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) with [cssselect](https://cssselect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can use `bs4` if preferred, the logic is the same, but I would highly encourage using `lxml`, the deps are outlined [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html), you will also need to `pip install cssselect`:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from typing import Iterator

url = "https://www.olx.com.ng/vehicles/cars/toyota/?search%5Bfilter_enum_model%5D%5B0%5D=toyota%2Fcamry"


def parse_data(node_: html.Element, price: str) -> dict:
    """Parses the details section per individual car details page and returns a dict"""

    # Price we pulled from main page.
    details = {"price": price.strip("₦ ")}

    # Details are in a table.
    details_table = node_.cssselect("table.details")[0]

    # The th has the description, the anchor has the value.
    # we lower case and join the description, i.e "Type of car" -> type_of_car.
    data = iter(details_table.cssselect("tr th, .value"))
    details.update(("_".join(th.text.lower().split()), "".join(td.xpath(".//text()")).strip())
                   for th, td in (zip(data, data)))
    return details


def get_link_and_price(s: requests.Session, node_: html.Element) -> Iterator[dict]:
    """Gets the link and the associated price from each tr."""

    for child in node_.cssselect("table.offers td.offer"):
        link, price = child.cssselect("a.link")[0].get("href"), child.cssselect(".price strong")[0].text

        yield (parse_data(html.fromstring(s.get(link).content), price))


def start_request(url: str):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        get_ = s.get(url)
        node = html.fromstring(get_.content)

        # yield from subsequent iterators, i.e a dict of details.
        yield from get_link_and_price(s, node)

        # The site is broken, you click the next page button,
        #  and eventually you get stuck in a loading loop.
        # At some stage the next should disappear,
        # or only go back but it is wrongly implemented.
        # This will stop when we try a next page,
        #  and end up back at the current url i.e ?page=501 -> ?page=500.
        current_url = get_.url
        next_page = node.cssselect("a.pageNextPrev")[-1].get("href")
        get_next = s.get(next_page)
        node = html.fromstring(get_next.content)

        # Keep going through pages till our break condition is met.
        while current_url != get_next.url:
            node = html.fromstring(get_next.content)
            yield from get_link_and_price(s, node)
            current_url = get_next.url
            next_page = node.cssselect("a.pageNextPrev")[-1].get("href")
            get_next = s.get(next_page)

for dict_ in start_request(url):
    print(dict_)
```

A snippet of the output:

```
{'price': '3,300,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2008', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '65000'}
{'price': '3,000,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2007', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '86500'}
{'price': '4,200,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2013', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '39011'}
{'price': '4,500,000', 'offer_from': 'Business', 'year': '2010', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '93000'}
{'price': '890,000', 'offer_from': 'Business', 'year': '2001', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '110000'}
{'price': '1,050,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2005', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': 'Low'}
{'price': '1,500,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2008', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': 'Low'}
{'price': '1,150,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2002', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '167'}
{'price': '2,200,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2010', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '24689'}
{'price': '1,050,000', 'offer_from': 'Individual', 'year': '2004', 'transmission': 'Automatic', 'model': 'Camry', 'type_of_car': '4 door', 'mileage': '92,000'}
```

Comment: Oh wow! I'm just seeing this. Thank you so much @padraic-cunningham